# Spark - Automated Deployment & Performance Testing

Tags: testing, sbt, bigdata, apache-spark

We are developing an application which uses Spark & Hive to do static and ad-hoc reporting. For these static reports, they take a number of parameters and then run over a data set. We would like to make it easier to test performance of these reports on a cluster.

If we have a test cluster running with a sufficient sample data set which developers can share. To speed up development time, what is the best way to deploy a Spark application to a Spark cluster (in standalone) via an IDE?

I'm thinking we would create an SBT task which would run the spark submit script. Is there a better way?

Eventually this will feed into some automated performance testing which we plan to run as a twice daily Jenkins job. If its an SBT deploy task, it makes it easy to call in Jenkins. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a [project on GitHub](https://github.com/databricks/spark-perf), maybe you can get some inspiration.

Maybe just add a for loop for submitting jobs and increase the loop times to find the performance limit, not sure if I'm right or not.